# How to change Socket type in node group with Python?

Tags: python, node-editor

I would like to understand if it is possible to change the socket type of the `bpy.data.node_groups['MyGroup']`, for example from 'VALUE' to 'RGBA' via python. I'm looking on Blender's bee page, and elsewhere as well. But we don't talk about this.

It seems that you have to create a new Socket, assigning the type, at the time of creation

Easy way to create a New socket:

```
>>> node_tree = D.node_groups['MyGroup']
>>> input = node_tree.inputs.new("NodeSocketFloatFactor",name="Test")
>>> input.bl_rna
<bpy_struct, Struct("NodeSocketInterfaceFloatFactor")>
```

it is now possible to change the socket type to `<bpy_struct, Struct ("NodeSocketInterfaceColor")>` ?

Comment: Don't think it is possible, internal data structure is defined when created. What do you want to do, changing it?

Comment: I agree with @lemon - not possible as far as I know. Only option is to add now one, move links, remove old one.

Comment: @lemon , yes i want to change the Socket type , in a easy way. There are many types of Sockets that you can use, but it is very inconvenient, especially when changing your mind, whether you want to show a slider or not. And many other situations that are really uncomfortable